# Facebook Audience Size NOT AVAILABLE (approximate_count = -1)

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

When I try to retrieve the facebook sdk / graph api custom audience current size API returns the `"approximate_count": -1.`

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/{custom_audience_id}?access_token={access_token}&fields=approximate_count,delivery_status,operation_status"]
```

Result =

```
{
    {
    "approximate_count": -1,
    "delivery_status": {
        "code": 200,
        "description": "This audience is ready for use."
    },
    "operation_status": {
        "code": 200,
        "description": "Normal"
    },
    "id": "{custom_audience_id}"
}
```

Here I expected to get the approximate_count as an actual value. But I am getting the -1. Any help ???

Comment: How old is the audience? Have you tried again more recently? I would think this would normally happen when the audience hasn't grown enough yet.